# Creating an instance of a form in a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, forms

I want to create a new instance of a form in a BackgroundWorker. I've noticed that when I do this, the newly launched form freezes.

[image: Frozen form]

Why does this form freeze? How can I get around this?

Comment: You shouldn't do that, What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I thing if you create the new Form from ReportProgress event, it will not freeze.

Comment: Thanks sh_kamalh, I'll keep that in mind for future projects. In this particular case, I decided to move the form creation to a function that was called upon `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's freezing because you're creating the form in the wrong thread - there's no event loop running in the background thread.

You should only create or touch UI elements in the UI thread. `BackgroundWorker` provides some hooks for this, or you can use `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 1):

When a form "runs" it needs to have a thread that runs the WndProc and handles incoming messages from Windows.  What you should consider doing here is using the `Application.Run()` method to start up your form.  This will do the necessary work to make sure the WndProc is running properly, and I belive you can call this from your Background thread if necessary.

Comment: You're partly right but this cannot come to a good end.  The thread that pumps a message loop must be STA to make basic stuff like cut and paste and drag+drop work.  The BGW thread is a threadpool thread, it is always MTA and cannot be changed.