# Task.Run() in C# doesn't execute some parts

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, multitasking

I want to do a task in background without freezing the main User Interface. However, I have some problem using Task.Run() with anonymous function in C# because it seems like it doesn't execute the code. I think my implementation may be incorrect.

```
private  List<string> GetPdfList
{
    get
    {
        return File.Directory.GetFiles(PDF_FILE_DIRECTORY);
    }
}

private  void InitializePdf()
{
    if (GetPdfList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var pdf in GetPdfList)
        {
            var converter = new PdfConvertor();
            var format = ImageFormat.Png;
            converter.Convert(pdf, TempFolder, format);
        }

    }
}


public  MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        InitializePdf();
    });
}
```

I think the problem is in **foreach scope**

Comment: set a breakpoint and use the debugger to check if a) execution reaches the loop at all and b) the list has elements. Also the constructor may not be the best place to create the thread. use the Load event or the (first) Activate event.

Comment: 'Might' be privilege problem, try running `InitializePdf();` on main thread to make sure that it's probem with `Task.Run(...)`

Comment: It works perfectly when it runs on the main thread

Answer (score -6):

Task.Run() creates the task, but doesn't execute it.
In order to do what you want, you should await for the task result in an async event.
See [Async loading for winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545071/async-loading-for-winforms)

Comment: That's not true. `Task.Run()` *does* start the task running, hence the name. Note that there's no result here.